# number manipulation in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I was trying to convert some number automatically from x=1 to x=00001 so that x takes 5 spaces in total. If x=20.2, I want to format x to be 00020. How can I do that?

I am using html and angularjs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
function convert(input)
{
    var a = Math.floor(input).toString();
    return ("00000").substr(0, 5 - a.length) + a;
}
```

Example:

```
console.log(convert(20.2)); // 00020
```

Comment: Thanks. It really helps. I know how to code it in C but JS is really new to me.

Answer (score 0):

write this filter to achieve the logic

```
<div>{{number | decimalConvertion:5}}</div>

   filter('decimalConvertion', function() {
     return function(str, max){
            function pad(str, max){
               str = str.toString();
               return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;        
            }
            return pad(str,8);
        };
   }
```

[for your reference  jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/francisstalin/6X8Wr/1/)